# How to add an attribute to an object at runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, object, attributes, runtime

I need to serialize any type of `object`. In order to serialize an `object`, it must have a `Serializable` **attribute**. So I need to add that **attribute** to **any** `object` at **runtime**. I think it's only possible by creating a new type using `System.Reflection`.

Here's a simple method that tests whether the `object` is **serializable** (has the `Serializable` attribute) or not.

```
bool IsObjectSerializable(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        // If it's not serializable (aka doesn't have the Serializable attribute) it will thrown an exception.
        formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);

        return true;
    }
    catch(SerializationException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have a **serializable** and a ***non*-serializable** class:

```
[Serializable]
class SerializableTestObject
{
}

class TestObject
{
}
```

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(IsObjectSerializable(new SerializableTestObject())); // prints true

    Console.WriteLine(IsObjectSerializable(new TestObject())); // prints false

    dynamic modifiedTestObject = AddAttributeToObject<SerializableAttribute>(new TestObject());
    Console.WriteLine(IsObjectSerializable(modifiedTestObject)); // should print true
}
```

What do I need to write in `AddAttributeToObject`?

I've done some research, but I found very little resources on this topic, and most people just say it's hard to do and stuff like that.

Comment: check this to customize attribute class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes that said your serialization part is another question.

Comment: Before you go to all this trouble, what kind of serialization are you talking about? You don't need a [Serializable] attribute for every kind of serialization.

Comment: Also that's really overkill just to check if the Serializable attribute is there. `obj.GetType().IsSerializable` will tell you that -- though Binary serialization like you show also supports `ISerializable` so your method can actually return a false positive if you're looking to only detect the attribute

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm talking about binary serialization.